# Issue in parsing JSON in Android

Tags: android, json, parsing

First of all, this is my json output.

> {"alert_id":"1","type":"Urgent","department":"Engineering Department","clas":"4","faculty":"Software Engineering","body":"Mike","date":"10.04.1990"}

This is parsing code.

```
package com.androidalert;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class AlertsJSON extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.alert);

        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.tuncayyildirim.com.tr/cagri_android_frontend/event_restful/event_handler/get_event.json");

        EditText textID = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textID);
        EditText textType = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textType);
        EditText textDepartment = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textDepartment);
        EditText textClass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textClass);
        EditText textFaculty = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textFaculty);
        EditText textBody = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textBody);
        EditText textDate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textDate);

        textID.setKeyListener(null);
        textType.setKeyListener(null);
        textDepartment.setKeyListener(null);
        textClass.setKeyListener(null);
        textFaculty.setKeyListener(null);
        textBody.setKeyListener(null);
        textDate.setKeyListener(null);

        try {

            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            String jsonResult = inputStreamToString(
                    response.getEntity().getContent()).toString();
            JSONObject object = new JSONObject(jsonResult);

            String id = object.getString("alert_id");
            String type = object.getString("type");
            String department = object.getString("department");
            String clas = object.getString("clas");
            String faculty = object.getString("faculty");
            String body = object.getString("body");
            String date = object.getString("date");

            textID.setText(id);
            textType.setText(type);
            textDepartment.setText(department);
            textClass.setText(clas);
            textFaculty.setText(faculty);
            textBody.setText(body);
            textDate.setText(date);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private StringBuilder inputStreamToString(InputStream is) {
        String rLine = "";
        StringBuilder answer = new StringBuilder();
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

        try {
            while ((rLine = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                answer.append(rLine);
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return answer;
    }
}
```

I think, code is correct but I can't show that JSON output in my application.

Comment: Are you getting `NetworkOnMainThreadException`?

Comment: Are you that you declared INTERNET permisson in your manifest file? Otherwise, LOG jsonResult variable's output via LOGCAT. Are watching the jsonResult variable has been initialize correctly?

Comment: @nesimtunc i did all of them.

Comment: OK. Create a class and try to use GSON to deserialize the object. Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17030702/how-to-parse-complicated-json-in-android/17030781#comment24618370_17030781) and [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/)

Answer (score 0):

The JSON object parsing looks correct, so the problem is in something else. First of all, you shouldn't (and actually can't in latests sdks) do networking on UI thread. Also, I would check your "jsonResult" value before parsing, if it receives the actual json.